# Recursive Feature Elimination (getting similar importance for all features)

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I´m trying to fit a model on a categorical variable (3 levels = low, mid, high) using 10 also categorical variables (all same scale 1 thru 10). I run Recursive feature elimination (RFE) with random forest and result is that ALL variables have a similar importance (~10% each). I was expecting a dominating variable but this is not the case. How can this be interpreted? Should I try modeling differently or this is just the nature of the data?

PS:I ran a corr matrix and all 10 features have low correlation levels with the target variable. If this is the case should I expect that there's no variable that dominates importance given the low levels of correlation?

Comment: "How can this be interpreted? Should I try modeling differently or this is just the nature of the data?" Without any information about the data it is impossible to answer this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking, yes it is possible that all your attributes have an equal influence. Whether this equality makes sense can only be answered with "insight knowledge" about the particular data set or domain.